# PHP , CODEIGNITER how to add from controller with hidden view

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, controller

I have problem that my input "type" is never post in database because I don't give input type in the view (I want value of my type is set by controller/hidden)... and this is my code

Controller :

```
<?php
    public function addSmsCampaign() {
    if (isset($_POST['addSmsCampaign'])) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('campaign_name', 'campaign name', 'required|is_unique[campaigns.campaign_name]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('sequence_qty', 'sequence quantity', 'required|integer');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('label_id', 'label id', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('type', '', 'required');

    //if form validation true
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            $sms = 1;

            $newcampaign = [
                'campaign_name' => $_POST['campaign_name'],
                'sequence_qty' => $_POST['sequence_qty'],
                'label_id' => $_POST['label_id'],
                'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d')
            ];
            $this->db->insert('campaigns', $newcampaign);
            redirect('userCont/sequenceform', 'refresh');
        }
    }
?>
```

and this is my view:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">    
        <label for="campaign_name">Input Campaign Title </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="campaign_name" id="name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sequence_qty">Sequence qty </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sequence_qty" id="qty">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="type" value="1">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="label_id">Choose Category</label>

        <select class="form-control"  name="label_id" id="label_id">
            <?php
            foreach ($label_content as $e) {
                echo "<option value='$e->id;'>" . $e->label_name . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="1" name="addSmsCampaign type">next</button>
    </div><hr>
</form>
```

every time I post value of type is default = 0, and I want set value to 1...
thanks a lot

Comment: you not need to include type field in html, just set value in controller

Comment: ***every time I post value of type is default = 0, and I want set value to 1*** ??? whare ?? explain your question

Comment: I edit type in my controller for type
'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
to this
'type' => '1',
but the value is still 0, thats why I set hidden in view but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing name from 'type' to some other name in db, controller and view